# Object reference not set to an instance of an object Error

Tags: database, nhibernate, connection

I'm trying to save text fields in MySql using NHibernate in Asp.Net frame work. But while executing this I got the error"Object reference not set to an instance of an object". If anyone knew help me...

Here is the code.

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack) 
{
   IList siteList; 
   ISessionFactory factory = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration().Configure().BuildSessionFactory(); 
   using (ISession session = factory.OpenSession()) 
   {
      ICriteria sc = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Employee )); 
      siteList = sc.List(); 
      session.Close(); 
   } 
   factory.Close(); 
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the relevant code?

Comment: if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                IList siteList;
                ISessionFactory factory = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration().Configure().BuildSessionFactory();
                using (ISession session = factory.OpenSession())
                {
                    ICriteria sc = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Employee ));
                    siteList = sc.List();
                    session.Close();
                }
                factory.Close();
            }

Answer (score 1):

**Can you post a stack trace? And a description of how you are configuring  **

If i had to take a guess the crash is in (because of missing/incorrect configuration information):

`new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration().Configure().Build().SessionFactory()`

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
<session-factory><property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property><property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver</property><property name="connection.connection_string">Server=localhost;Database=hrms;User ID=root;Password=siva;CharSet=latin1</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
    <mapping assembly="WebApplication1" />
  </session-factory></hibernate-configuration>

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
<session-factory>
<property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property><property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver</property><property name="connection.connection_string">Server=localhost;Database=hrms;User ID=root;Password=siva;CharSet=latin1</property>
<property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
<mapping assembly="WebApplication1" />
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>